# Printing stamp albums

Tags: packages, tex-general

Is there any TeX package well suited for producing stamp albums?

Some examples of stamp album pages can be seen [here](http://www.stampalbums.com/images/sample2a.JPG), [here](http://www.stampcollectingblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/uruguya-stamp-album-page.jpg), [here](http://cdn.iofferphoto.com/img3/item/205/507/844/spain-stamp-album-pages-1850-2010-732-pages-d3c6.jpg) or [here](http://i292.photobucket.com/albums/mm23/ScotsmanAbroad/my%20stampboard/Stamp%20pages/QVEmpireBarbados1.jpg).

In particular, captions can go anywhere around the frames and might be common to 2 or more frames.

Comment: The second link is not accessible.

Comment: It is, but not if you click it. If you paste it on the address bar it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know of any packages, but one approach is to brew-your-own.  The `stackengine` package helps with vertical stacking issues.  To turn this MWE into a specific example, just substitute `\includegraphics` where I have the `\rule` in the definition of `\stamp`, replacing argument 4 with a filename, in the manner of the macro `\actualstamp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\topic[1]{\textbf{#1}\\}
\newcommand\stamp[4][]{\stackon{\stackunder{\fbox{\rule{#3}{#4}}}{#2}}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\actualstamp[4][]{\stackon{\stackunder{%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=#3]{#4}}}{#2}}{\textbf{#1}}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\centering
\textbf{2009}
~\\
\topic{LaTeX 25th Anniversary}
15 March

\raisebox{1.2cm}{\stamp{Knuth}{1.5cm}{2cm}}
\hspace{0,5cm}
\stackon[1cm]{\stamp{egreg}{2cm}{1.5cm}}%
% USE ONE OF FOLLOWING TWO LINES; 2ND IF YOU HAVE IMAGE
   {\stamp{Carlisle}{2cm}{1.5cm}}
%  {\actualstamp{Carlisle}{2cm}{carlisle}}
\hspace{0,5cm}
\raisebox{1.2cm}{\stamp{Lamport}{1.5cm}{2cm}}
\vspace{1cm}

\topic{Packages}
4 June

\raisebox{1.2cm}{\stamp[Images]{graphicx}{1.8cm}{1.5cm}}
\hspace{0,5cm}
\stackon[1cm]{\stamp[Equations]{amsmath}{1.8cm}{1.5cm}}{\stamp[Graphics]{tikz}{1.5cm}{1.8cm}}
\hspace{0,5cm}
\raisebox{1.2cm}{\stamp[\stackon{\& Captions}{Figures}]{\stackon{V1.0}{boxhandler}}{1.8cm}{1.5cm}}
\\
\stamp[Tables]{tabularx}{1.8cm}{1.5cm}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\stamp[Stacking]{stackengine}{1.8cm}{1.5cm}

\end{document}
```

EDITED to give credit where credit is due.  Knuth stamp re-valued on REEDIT, per barbara's comment

[image]

Comment: Would be a lot of fun to see these stamps become reality ...

Comment: @Chris Done, per your request ;^)

Comment: the knuth stamp should really have a value of $2.56 (the base value of one of his reward checks).

Comment: I was trying this for a photo album, but it seems very complicated. Can you simplify the explanation for how this would apply to an arbitrary number of images of various sizes? Or is this example particular to this specific situation?

Comment: @user219110 Well, the complexity will depend on the desired layout.  If you just wanted several stamps in a row, and then skip to the next row and repeat, you could `\setstackEOL{\\}` to define the stacking line break and perhaps use `\Shortstack{StampA StampB StampC\\StampD StampE StampF\\StampG...}`, where `Stampx` is replaced by the appropriately sized stamp graphic.  You should take a look at the `stackengine` and or the `tabstackengine` documentation (https://ctan.org/search?phrase=stackengine)