# Best way to make family photo album in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I use LaTeX for my research publishing and would like to make a Christmas photo album that I could send to a print shop. It occurred to me to try it with LaTeX this time (yes I know, the print version won't get delivered by Christmas). Among other reasons, it will look like I'm working on code! But I would benefit from some templates etc. and haven't had luck finding any.

Can anyone recommend resources for building a family photo album in LaTeX?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? It's not difficult to place pictures at arbitrary locations on a page. What more do you need?

Comment: I can think of several ways programming could aid album creation. I'm not saying these are the functions I expect to see in the package as someone may have thought of other things. But a set of standard layouts, preferably full bleed, as environments; easy page backdrops; flexible captioning (easy to place above, below, left, right, middle). In other words, beamer makes it easy to make slides with very economical use of LaTeX code. I can do all these things in my album, but the code won't be economical. Someone might know a package that handles these issues well.

Comment: Also default centering of page contents...

Comment: I once answered a question about typesetting stamp albums at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130658/printing-stamp-albums/130660#130660.  While the image sizes would be different, as well as other aspects, it might give you one idea on how to arrange photos, add captions, organize, etc.  But it would help to know more of what you have in mind, in order to help us give good suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

I looked at stackengine and found it too cumbersome.  I figured one could use Tikz to place the pictures anywhere easily, using either absolute or relative coordinates.  Using pdfscreen gives you complete control over the paper size, background color or image.

Note: replace rabbit.jpg with your own images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}% additional colors by name
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}

\margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
\screensize{6in}{10in}
\backgroundcolor{ForestGreen}
%\overlay{supper.png}% background picture (not used)

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}% vertically center
\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\node[fill=Gold](p1) at (0,0)% for absolute cordinates, if any
 {\resizebox{2in}{!}{\includegraphics{rabbit.jpg}}};
\node[above=2mm,fill=red,text=white] at (p1.north) {caption};
% .25in gap and raise .5in
\node[right,fill=Navy](p2) at ($(p1.east)+(.25in,.5in)$)
 {\resizebox{2in}{!}{\includegraphics{rabbit.jpg}}};
\node[below=2mm,fill=red,text=white] at (p2.south) {caption};
% ditto
\node[right,fill=Silver](p3) at ($(p2.east)+(.25in,.5in)$)
 {\resizebox{2in}{!}{\includegraphics{rabbit.jpg}}};
\node[rotate=90,below=2mm,fill=red,text=white] at (p3.east) {sideways};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

[image: photos]

Comment: Can you explain how the absolute coordinates work? If I want the first image laid out from the top right of the page and then other images relative to that, how would that work?

Comment: For true absolute coordinates one should use [overlay, remember picture] and use the (current page) node anchors.  So the top right corner would be (current page.north east).  Note that these anchors are not defined until the second time the document is run.