# how to compose many pictures tightly in LaTex as follow

Tags: graphics

I want to compose some pictures as the example picture. All small pictures need to be ranked alignedly, and the subcaption of each row should be near to the pictures.

[image: 1]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/best-way-to-make-family-photo-album-in-latex although in your case you would want to use (x,y) coordinates instead of edge alignment.

Comment: Try the `subcaption` package, make an attempt and see if it works.  If it doesn't, please feel free to ask any question to the community here :) ---don't forget to include the code!

Comment: So is the problem placing the little pictures in front of the big ones, packing the big ones tightly, creating the color legend, or just writing captions and subcaptions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package for this. It allows you to define some `subfigure`s inside a `figure` environment. You can use it like this :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture_01}
        \caption{My first picture}
        \label{fig:pic01}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture_02}
        \caption{My second picture}
        \label{fig:pic02}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture_03}
        \caption{My third picture}
        \label{fig:pic03}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{All of my pictures}
    \label{fig:pic_all}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```