# How to insert multiple pictures in page

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I have many PNG files, and I want to put them in a latex page in certain positions. Could you please help me how?

I cannot use tabular idea, as many of images are diagonal and using table does not let use of all the page.

I have tried the following so far, which has two problems:

```
\def\Put(#1,#2)#3{\leavevmode\makebox(0,0){\put(#1,#2){#3}}}
\Put(0,0){ \includegraphics[width=2in]{alanine.png} }
\Put(100,0){  \includegraphics[width=2in]{arginine.png} }
```

1. I don't know how to caption each image.
2. The whitespace of one image covers the other image.

One of the images is as follows:
[image]

Comment: You need to show what you have tried. -and a picture of what you want.

Comment: Especially the bit about the images being diagonal. I've never come across a PNG which was not rectangular. I strongly suspect that TeX is not the right tool for the job. (Not to say it can't be done in LaTeX. Just to say that it probably shouldn't be.)

Comment: Can you provide some diagonal pictures?

Comment: The drawing in the picture is diagonal. They are mainly genes and proteins. To use the space in the page I want my images overlap when they have white spaces.

Comment: The best solution so far I have found is to use \put(x,y){\includegraphics{1.png}}, but I have the problem of captioning and overlapping. The whitespace of one covers the other images.

Comment: Using an image editor you can replace a white background with a transparent one.  Tikz is your best package for overlapping images and adding captions in odd locations.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/best-way-to-make-family-photo-album-in-latex?s=1|3.2013 as an example.

Answer (score 3):

So, I took a [previous answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213286/christmas-list-catalog/213293#213293) and made it more serious by using captions rather than just minipage text. The I took your image saved it as `molecule-orig.png` and used imagemagic convert:

```
 convert molecule-orig.png -transparent white molecule.png
```

So the background in `molecule.png` is transparent and doesn't obscure the car.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,capt-of}
\begin{document}

\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\begin{picture}(0,0)\bfseries\large
\put(4,3){\includegraphics{house}}
\put(0.5,5){\parbox{5cm}{\raggedright
\captionof{figure}{If you are feeling generous 
I'd like a house, preferably one with architectural
design integrity, like this}}}

\put(0,17){\includegraphics{car}}
\put(8,21.5){\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright
\captionof{figure}{I'd like a \textbf{Car},
preferably with four wheels.}}}

\put(0,10){\includegraphics{computer}}
\put(0,9){\parbox{6cm}{\raggedright
\captionof{figure}{A new \textbf{computer}
would be nice. (I won't need vim)}}}



\put(8,12){\includegraphics{cake}}
\put(9,11.5){\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{Cake}, of course}}}


\put(5,15){\includegraphics[scale=.4]{molecule}}
\put(10,18){\parbox{3cm}{\raggedright
\captionof{figure}{one of these is apparently needed}}}


\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are almost the father of Latex Mr. Carlisle. I am so honoured to receive this very illustrative and educational answer from you.

Comment: Good God, David…