# Asymptote: re-use picture

Tags: asymptote

I have drawn a picture using the asymptote package (`\usepackage{asymptote}`), and the environment `\begin{asy}...\end{asy}`. I want to recycle the code in the `{asy}` environment without have to copy-paste it.

- Is it possible to save result of drawing inside the `{asy}` block to insert it at a different location in the same document?
- Is it possible to save chunks of code asy-code, i.e. subpictures, to re-use them somewhere else?

For example, I might draw a green disk, and somewhere else a red disk. At different points in my document I might want to insert other, exactly the same looking green and red disks without copy-pasting the code. At some point I might even want to insert a picture that contains both the green and the red disk combined/overlaid in some way to give one picture.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Re-written the discription in a (hopefully) clearer way.

Comment: \savebox is the fastest, most efficient way to produce multiple copies of pretty much anything.  One can use tikz to arrayge other images.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/best-way-to-make-family-photo-album-in-latex for example.

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 4):

Here is an attempt to answer both questions using the `asypictureB` package (which is an alternative interface to Asymptote). It takes advantage of the fact that when using `asypictureB` you can name your Asymptote pictures, and use that name to recall the graphics produced. Note that `\jobname` is essentially the name of your master `tex` file; for instance, if this file were called `foo.tex`, then `\jobname` would expand to `foo`.

For the second question, I take advantage of the `include` command in Asymptote, which directly includes the code from a specified Asymptote file. Also note that within an `asypicture` environment, `@jobname` behaves like `\jobname` would outside the environment (with a number of very strong caveats explained in [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/asypictureb/asypictureB.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
A red disk:
\begin{center}
\begin{asypicture}{name=red_disk}
size(3cm);
fill(unitcircle, red);
\end{asypicture}
\end{center}
%
A green disk:
\begin{center}
\begin{asypicture}{name=green_disk}
size(4cm);
fill(unitcircle, green);
\end{asypicture}
\end{center}
%
A red disk and a green disk:
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{\jobname-red_disk}
\hspace{1cm}
\includegraphics{\jobname-green_disk}
\end{center}
%
A red disk and a green disk in the same \verb!asypicture!:
\begin{center}
\begin{asypicture}{name=overlay}
// Execute all the code from the red_disk asypicture.
include "@jobname-red_disk";

// Save the resulting picture and start a new one.
picture reddisk = currentpicture;
currentpicture = new picture;

// Execute all the code from the green_disk asypicture.
include "@jobname-green_disk";

// Save the resulting picture and start a new one.
// Note that the scale information from the previous 
// pictures is lost. If you want to retain it, look into 
// using frames instead of pictures.
picture greendisk = currentpicture;
currentpicture = new picture;
unitsize(1cm);
add(shift(-0.3,0)*greendisk);
add(shift(0.3,0)*reddisk);
\end{asypicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: a page showing the result of the code above]

Comment: it's very helpful! it should be included in your document on asypictureB package