# Christmas cards suggestions?

Tags: jpeg

Do some of you have good suggestions, with minimal working examples, for Christmas greeting cards? I did not find any suggestions by means of searching.

Comment: Did you search https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfun%5D+Christmas ? I’ve used some of the trees drawn with TikZ.

Comment: [A recent add at TeXample](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/totoro/).

Comment: You could do the "photo album" card trick.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/best-way-to-make-family-photo-album-in-latex

Comment: You can even try to adapt some playing cards such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185830/162128).

Comment: @this It would have been nice if it came with mwe.